Is there a realistic threshold for formula complexity which might indicate consistency?
Many arguments in favour of the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and similar systema point to their empirical usage throughout the years without the apparition of any purported inconsistencies. While I agree wholly with such observations, I'm also left to wonder: could that be because, realistically speaking, we only ever utilize a minute fraction of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ during our proofmaking? Particularly, the Comprehension and Replacement schemata "quantify" over all possible formulae of the language of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Again, realistically speaking, has any mathematician ever utilized, say, a $\Sigma_{42!}$ sentence throughout her proof? Could it be that the apparent wellbehavedness of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is only so given our limited range in formula usage? (After all, something as complex as RH is only really $\Pi_1$!)
I ask then, in addition to the above conundrum, is there any sort of prooftheoretical result which might make "unnecessary" the worry over the possibility of inconsistency above a certain complexity level (provided the respective lower strata are themselves, of course, consistent)?

You ask: could it be that the apparent wellbehavedness of ZFC is only so given our limited range in formula usage?. And yes, this very well could be, but it's also not ZFC-specific: it could similarly happen that induction (and hence Peano Arithmetic) itself breaks down for very complex formulas on the naturals. Gentzen's consistency proof for PA allows us to at least "reduce" inductions on complex formulas to longer (transfinite) inductions on simpler formulas, but no comparable result is available for ZFC at this stage.

Related: Is anyone aware of a relative consitency result of the form: Cons(ZFC restricted to $\Pi_n$ for some n) Implies Cons(ZFC) ?

@MichaelCarey: As a consequence of Montague's reflection principle, such results cannot exist (unless ZFC is inconsistent).
